# Setting moreViewController TableView background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

after spending hours trying to fix this I guess I’ve tried everything I could and I’m here to ask for some help :)

I got a more `UINavigationController` with 3 rows in the `UITableView`, I can set the background of the three cell but the other empty cells are in a different color (and I just don’t understand where it takes that color!)

I’ve tried to set the `UITableView` background color but there’s no way to do it, it never changes: where I am wrong? Because I must be wrong in something.

Following it’s the code I wrote.

How would you change the remaining empty cell or fix the `UITableView` background color?

```
…

[[[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:4]tabBarItem]setTitle:@"Settings"];

[[[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:5]tabBarItem]setTitle:@"Hazards"];

[[[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:6]tabBarItem]setTitle:@"Beaufort Scale"];

…

UIViewController *tabBarMore =      [tabBarController.moreNavigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

[tabBarMore.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:3.0/255.0 green:30.0/255.0 blue:100.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

NSDictionary *textAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [UIColor whiteColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                    nil]; 

tabBarMore.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes;

tabBarMore.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"More";



UITableView *moreTableView = (UITableView *)tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view;


int n = (int)[((UITableView *)tabBarMore.view) numberOfRowsInSection:0];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [((UITableView *)tabBarMore.view) cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];

        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:20.0/255.0 green:41.0/255.0 blue:97.0/255.0 alpha:1]];

        static NSString *cellId = @"Cell";
        cell = [((UITableView *)tabBarMore.view) dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set backgound after you define static cellld.